# Checkstyle AbstractClassName check: Reasons for flagging classes ending with "Factory"

Tags: java, design-patterns, naming-conventions, checkstyle

Checkstyle's "[AbstractClassName](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_naming.html#AbstractClassName)" check uses the following default pattern to check for class names that should be declared as *abstract*:

```
^Abstract.*$|^.*Factory$
```

I understand that classes starting with 'Abstract' are supposed to be declared as abstract. But why should this also hold true for classes ending with 'Factory'?

Is this really best practice? And if so how should I name my factory classes instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default regular expression came about from the Abstract Factory pattern - see http://www.apwebco.com/gofpatterns/creational/AbstractFactory.html.

I admit that I have not seen this naming convention used *in the wild*. It is a simple matter to change the check configuration to use the pattern:

```
^Abstract.*$
```

Like always, Checkstyle should be used as *guide* as to what is best practice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was assuming this to be the reason for this rule too as first. But the 'Abstract Factory' design pattern does always require a concrete factory (the implementation(s) of the abstract factory's interface). As can be seen in the linked example the names of the concrete factories also end with _Factory_, resulting in being flagged as violations.

Answer (score 2):

A slight expansion to Oliver's answer (wasn't easy to add as a comment). To change the Checkstyle rule to no longer check for "Factory", put the following in the checkstyle configuration XML file:

```
<module name="AbstractClassName">
  <property name="format" value="^Abstract.*$"/>
</module>
```

See [here](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_naming.html) for further details.